# SOLR 8.1.1 SynonymQuery(Synonym in parsedQuery

Tags: apache, solr

I have a SOLR 4.10.2 core, and I am upgrading to 8.1.1.

When I compare parsedQuery for a search 4.10 vs 8.1.1 I am seeing the query wrapped with SynonymQuery(Synonym( in 8.1.1.

I think it may be because I replaced the deprecated SynonymFilterFactory with SynonymGraphFilterFactory.

Is this a new feature of the SynonymGraphFilterFactory? How can I remove that (or should I?)?

4.10.2

```
"querystring":"IDX_Company:blue",
    "parsedquery":"(IDX_Company:b IDX_Company:bl IDX_Company:blu IDX_Company:blue)",
...
```

8.1.1

```
"querystring":"IDX_Company:blue",
    "parsedquery":"SynonymQuery(Synonym(IDX_Company:b IDX_Company:bl IDX_Company:blu IDX_Company:blue))",
...
```

Here's the field def:

```
<field name="Company" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
<field name="IDX_Company" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="false" multiValued="true" />
<copyField source="Company" dest="IDX_Company"/>
```

Here is the definition of text_general I am using in schema.xml

```
<fieldType name="text_general" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100" multiValued="true">
      <analyzer type="index">
        <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.EdgeNGramFilterFactory" minGramSize="1" maxGramSize="15"/> <!-- RDH - removed side="front"-->
        <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt" />
        <!-- RDH SynonymFilterFactory has been deprecated, replace with SynonymGraphFilterFactory -->
        <filter class="solr.SynonymGraphFilterFactory" synonyms="synonyms.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="true"/> 
        <!-- RDH https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/8_1/filter-descriptions.html
            Flatten Graph Filter
            This filter must be included on INDEX-time analyzer specifications that include at least one graph-aware filter, including Synonym Graph Filter and Word Delimiter Graph Filter.
        -->
        <filter class="solr.FlattenGraphFilterFactory"/>  
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
        <!-- strip all punctuation -->
        <filter class="solr.PatternReplaceFilterFactory" pattern="[^\p{L}\p{N} ]" replacement=" " replace="all" /> <!-- RDH -->
      </analyzer>
      <analyzer type="query">
        <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>       
        <filter class="solr.EdgeNGramFilterFactory" minGramSize="1" maxGramSize="15"/> <!-- RDH - removed side="front"-->
        <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt" />
        <!-- RDH SynonymFilterFactory is deprecated, replace with SynonymGraphFilterFactory -->
        <filter class="solr.SynonymGraphFilterFactory" synonyms="synonyms.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="true"/>
        <!-- RDH https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/8_1/filter-descriptions.html
            Flatten Graph Filter
            This filter must be included on INDEX-time analyzer specifications that include at least one graph-aware filter, including Synonym Graph Filter and Word Delimiter Graph Filter.
        -->
        <filter class="solr.FlattenGraphFilterFactory"/>  
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
        <!-- strip all punctuation -->
        <filter class="solr.PatternReplaceFilterFactory" pattern="[^\p{L}\p{N} ]" replacement=" " replace="all" /> <!-- RDH -->
      </analyzer>
    </fieldType>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you mean expansion of `blue => b, bl, blu, blue`, it's due to `EdgeNGramFilterFactory` that you have in schema of text_general.

But `SynonymQuery` that you see in parsed query is due to `SynonymGraphFilterFactory`, although synonym expansion really didn't happened since you might not have synonym for ***blue*** present in your synonyms.txt file.

You can remove it simply by removing `filter` associated with SynonymGraphFilterFactory from the schema, if you don't want synonym matching at all.